# what are the fees to purchase a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan license for Autocomplete feature?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoder

I have implemented Autocomplete feature using the Google Places API and Google Geocoder API.
Below link provides the information about the Map API Credits:
[a link] https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits

but I would like to know what are the fees to purchase these credits?

Thanks[image]

Comment: At that link, did you not see "pricing and plans" at the very top?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most straightforward way to get this information is reaching out to Google Maps API sales team.

You can send your question to sales team using the following web form:

https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/

Hope this helps!